# 新たに作成するテーブルに対して特定のユーザーのみアクセスできるようにしたい

Tags: mysql

特定のユーザーのみテーブルにアクセスできるようにするには `create table` する際に `identified by ''` をすればいいですか？ それとも後で `grant` するべきですか？

Comment: 「特定のユーザーのみ許容」というのがよくわかりません。「新たに作成するテーブルに対して特定のユーザーのみアクセスできるようにしたい」ということでしょうか？

Comment: そうです そういうことです

Answer (score 0):

`identified by` はユーザー作成時にパスワードを指定するためのものなので、`create table` では使用できません。

ユーザーがテーブルにアクセスするためにはユーザー作成後に `grant` で権限を付与する必要があります。

テーブルの SELECT だけ許可するのであれば

```
grant select on DB名.テーブル名 to ユーザー名
```

を指定します。
テーブルに対するすべての操作を許可するのであれば

```
grant all on DB名.テーブル名 to ユーザー名
```

と指定します。

Comment: ありがとうございます

Comment: ちなみにphpで設定するには''で設定すればいいですか ？

Comment: 「''で設定すればいい」の意味がわかりません…。

Comment: 新しくインスタンスを作成するときに$sql=''ということです

Comment: すいません、よくわかりません。